# How to keep the eventlistener real time for chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener, double-click

How would I go about calling my function in a way that it is always running. 
I want to get the text selection wherever the user double clicks. So I don't know how to attach the eventlistener that always stays on. not just a one time function when the document is loaded. but more like an ongoing eventlistener as long as the tab is open?

Thanks you so much!

Comment: So, you mean like even when the user visits a different page in the same tab, the listener should be applied there as well ? what element do you attach the listener to ? How do you decide what tab to activate this feature on ? What have you tried thus far ?

Comment: exactly, even if they visit different page, they would still be able to double click and get the selected word. you can imagine something like Google dictionary. it works on all pages, tabs. What elements should I attache the eventlistener to? thanks @ExpertSystem

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. Please, give some more context. E.g. what you want to happen (_"the user double-clicks on some text, the text gets selected and..."_ what then ?)

Comment: @ExpertSystem Double-click some text on the page, and log the selected text into the console. that's the example I'm looking for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you describe (and to have it always available on every tab), you can use a **[content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)** and have it injected in every page (see code below).
If you want it to be bound to a specific tab only, you can utilize an **[event page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)** (i.e. a non-persistent background page) and register a listener for the **[`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated)** event and **[programmatically inject](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)** the content script every time a new page is loaded in the specified tab.

In the aforementioned content script, you can attach an event-listener to the `document` itself to capture all events.

---

Below is the source code of a sample extension that adds the desired "feature" to every tab:

**content.js**

```
var listener = function(evt) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        var text = range.cloneContents().textContent;
        console.log(text);
    }
};
document.addEventListener('dblclick', listener);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": true,

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["<all_urls>"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to call the javascript on a persistent manner, you must define a contentScript and call the js from there. 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/developing-google-chrome-extensions/